# Hibernate hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" update doesn't run

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc

When i use the below line in property file and run application as java application.
Program doesn't terminate and it doesn't show any result.
There will be  no changes in database side as well.

If i replace 'update' with 'create', my table will be dropped and re created.
If i remove the property, program will run fine.

I want to create table if doesn't exist and update if exists.

**update**

OUTPUT:

> *INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@6a9d5dff] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.*

Comment: *When i use the below line in property file* there is no "relevant line below"

Comment: Please add your file, so we can understand what is the problem.

Comment: The 'below line' is still missing, there's no way to answer this question.

Answer (score -1):

I cannot determine the exact issue since the information provided is very less.
But I can help you figure out your issue. Please go through the following documentation. I guess,it will help you.

[Hibernate config explained](https://github.com/richy7734/GitSample/wiki/Spring-ORM,-JPA-and-Hibernate)

*Please let me know if it helped you.*

Comment: <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property> if this property is used in cfg.xml, program doesn't run(we have to terminate it manually).

Comment: Where it the applications runs fine for <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>.  but i don't want to use create, as it doprs and creates tables

Comment: i am using Hibernate 5.3.3 final, java8 and oracle11g, ojdbc6.jar

Comment: Okay.. Just tell me does the create option dropped the table and automatically re-created the tables for you.

Comment: Use <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

Answer (score -1):

check your HQL once
String hql = "from com.app.Model.Emplyee";

In my case i have written wrong package name

String hql = "from com.app.model.Emplyee";

Comment: I don't understand the link between this answer and the original question, which did not provide enough information in the first place. Why would this allow auto update in Hibernate to work?